# React - How to import monday view in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I woudlike to implement in my react component one of my monday board here :

```
import React from 'react'
import useI18n from 'hooks/useI18n'
import Page from 'components/layout/Page'


const Roadmap: React.FC = () => {
  const TranslateString = useI18n()
  return (
    <Page>
      <div>
        
      </div>
    </Page>
  )
}

export default Roadmap
```

I found this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/monday-ui-react-core
But I don't understand how it works and how it link to my monday board.

Comment: In the npmjs link you sent here have all the information you need to begin. You need to install it using npm install, then import in your component

Answer (score 0):

First you must install the monday package with the following command in a terminal:

```
npm install monday-ui-react-core
```

Notice: That you are in the root folder of your project where you created your react app.

After the successful installation the monday package is in our node_modules folder.

To import the new monday package:

```
import React from 'react'
import useI18n from 'hooks/useI18n'
import Page from 'components/layout/Page'
import { Button } from "monday-ui-react-core";
import "monday-ui-react-core/dist/main.css"

const Roadmap: React.FC = () => {
  const TranslateString = useI18n()
  return (
    <Page>
      <div>
        <Button></Button>
        ...
      </div>
    </Page>
  )
}

export default Roadmap
```